# How to show toolPopup for text longer than control (Textbox) length?

Tags: c#

Is there an easy way to say, on textboxHover, if the text inside the box or in other control
isn't completely visible, have a popup tool come up showing the complete
contents of the box? 
Just like
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a ToolTip programmatically and you can set the position:

```
private void textBox1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ToolTip t = new ToolTip();
    t.Show(textBox1.Text, textBox1, 0,0, 5000);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all you have to check if the text fits with the current width. If not you have to create a tooltip for the textbox only once (not like John's approach).

```
private void textBox1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Tag != null) return;
    Size s = TextRenderer.MeasureText(textBox1.Text, textBox1.Font);
    if (s.Width > textBox1.Width)
    {
        ToolTip t = new ToolTip(this.components);
        t.SetToolTip(textBox1, textBox1.Text);
    }
    textBox1.Tag = 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why the manipulate the textBox1.Tag ? Doesn't seem necesary?

Comment: The above piece of code is the half part. My initial approach was not only to create a tooltip once but also to use a 3-state flag [ie tag in this case] to control the flow of the routine, the tooltip creation and finally it's visibility. Sometimes speedy answers cut words and code, usually not succefuly :). Glad you noticed and asked.

Comment: Suggested a modification to the code snippet to remove the obsolete the tri-state related code to reduce code-noise to this example :)

Answer (score 0):

Add a [ToolTip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.aspx) control, and set the ToolTipText to show the full contents of the Textbox.

ps. The ToolTipText property will be added to every control the ToolTip supports, meaning your Textboxes will have a ToolTipText property added to them.